# How to properly get radio button value

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I need a bit of help with getting the value of a few radio buttons. I seemed to have done it correctly at first but now it is throwing built in errors.

Code: http://pastie.org/8534504

Comment: Please include your relevant code and the specific errors you receive in your question itself.

Comment: dont link  to your code, put it in the question

Comment: That's super difficult seeing as it never wants to format right from this device. The thing is, it must not be getting the right value because the switch statement is failing.

Comment: Please show us a (non-)working example at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: FYI, better use pc ( preferably linux ) or mac for web development.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7DU9c/ this does rely on MediaWiki variables and methods so this demo is useless. Also no money == no pc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var wgServer = mw.config.get("wgServer");

        function powerpagemaker() {
            var wgPageName = mw.config.get("wgPageName"),
                pagetitle = "New_Page";

            if (wgPageName !== pagetitle) {
                return;
            }

            var html = '<form style="width: 75%;"><fieldset><legend>Create a New Page</legend><input type="radio" name="namespace" value="main" checked="checked">Main</input><input type="radio" name="namespace" value="blog">Blog</input><input type="radio" name="namespace" value="category">Category</input><input type="radio" name="namespace" value="mediawiki">MediaWiki</input><input type="radio" name="namespace" value="template">Template</input><br/><br/><input type="text" id="NewPageTitle" style="width: 80%;" placeholder="Page title"/><br/><br/><span>Page Content: </span><input type="radio" name="pagecontent" value="blank" checked="checked">Blank</input><input type="radio" name="pagecontent" value="populated">Populated</input><br/><br/><button type="button" onclick="makenewpage()" style="float: right;">Create</button></fieldset></form>';

            document.getElementById("WikiaArticle").innerHTML = html;
        }

        function makenewpage() {
            var namespace,
                pagetosend = document.getElementById("NewPageTitle").value || "NULL",
                content;

            if (pagetosend == "NULL") {
                alert("Please give the name of a page to create");
            }

            var radioname = document.getElementsByName("namespace"),
                radiocont = document.getElementsByName("pagecontent");

            for (var i = 0; i < radioname.length; i++) {
                if (radioname[i].checked) {
                    namespace = radioname[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < radiocont.length; i++) {
                if (radiocont[i].checked) {
                    content = radiocont[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }

            var link;
            switch (namespace) {
                case "main":
                    if (content == 'populated') {
                        link = 'http://' + wgServer + '/wiki/' + pagetosend + '?action=edit&useFormat=1';
                    } else {
                        link = 'http://' + wgServer + '/wiki/' + pagetosend + '?action=edit';
                    }
                    break;
                case "blog":
                    link = 'http://' + wgServer + '/wiki/Special:CreateBlogPage';
                    break;
                case "category":
                    link = 'http://' + wgServer + '/wiki/Category:' + pagetosend + '?action=edit';
                    break;
                case "mediawiki":
                    link = 'http://' + wgServer + '/wiki/MediaWiki:' + pagetosend + '?action=edit';
                    break;
                case "template":
                    link = 'http://' + wgServer + '/wiki/Template:' + pagetosend + '?action=edit';
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('ERROR');
                    return;
            }
            window.location = link;
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            powerpagemaker()
        });
```